# Grab the minified version in ractive module with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ractivejs

I'm working with ractive and webpack in my front end application.
The bundle size of my application is very big (1.3M), so I was thinking instead of minify the node modules with webpack, should be better to grab the already minified version of some modules ? for example in the case of ractive, the **ractive** module builds minified versions in `node_modules/ractive` when you install it via `npm install ractive`, so I'd like to tell webpack to grab this file instead of compress the whole file.

**ractive.js** size is

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 413K Apr 25 17:53 ractive.js`

**ractive.min.js** is

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 162K Apr 25 17:53 ractive.min.js`

**Is there any way to tell this to webpack ?**

Maybe instead of writing

`var R = require('ractive')`

should be beter to write

`var R = require('./node_modules/ractive/ractive.min.js')`

I don't like this option since it seems too hacky, but if there is no way to do it well with webpack, I would have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When webpack bundles source files, it doesn't minify them by default. This is probably why you end up with a large bundle file. You can run `webpack -p` in order to get the minified version of the bundle file. This will result a file size similar to a bundle which was using ractive-min as source in the first place.

If you still want to work with the minified version of ractive in development you could use [`NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin). Here is an example:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    // other configuration settings

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^ractive$/, 'ractive/ractive.min')
    ]
};
```